# Keyboard Extension と ViewControllerの間で，データの受け渡しが出来ない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3, ios10

CapabilitiesのGroup設定はしています。

下記コードにて，ViweControllerで値を設定し，KeyboardExtension側で設定した値を受け取りたいのですが，nil(と言うことは、設定出来ていないのか、取得に失敗している)しか取得出来ません。

Groupを使用するのが正しいのか，別の手段が必要なのか，もしGroupの使用で正しければ，どうするとデータの受け渡しが出来るのか，教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //設定
        let defaults: UserDefaults! = UserDefaults(suiteName: "NameOfAppGroup")
        defaults.set("SharedStrings", forKey: "MyKey")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

KeyboardViewController.swift

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 取得
        var defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "NameOfAppGroup")
        let objects = defaults!.object(forKey: "MyKey") as? String
        print("表示:" , objects)
    ・・・    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }
・・・
}
```

Comment: _CapabilitiesのGroup設定はしています_ とありますが、それ以外のデータ共有に関する設定は全て済まされているでしょうか。([収容アプリケーションとデータを共有する](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6)) アプリケーショングループの設定方法に関しては、"ios app group 使い方"等で検索すれば多数の日本語記事が出てきます。(KeyboardExtensionに特化した記事は見当たらないかもしれませんが、Extensionと収容アプリ側のデータ共有方法は基本的にどのExtensionでも同じです。)一度各記事を読まれた上でお試しいただいた方が(もし十分読まれた上でご質問されているのなら、そのことをご質問中に明記していただいた方が)良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指導いただいたところを検索し，参照してみました。その上で，もう一度テスト用の最低限のプロジェクト作成から，コード追加，groupsの設定2箇所をし直してみました。今度はうまくいきました。group名のスペルミスだったようです。お騒がせいたしました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。大してお役に立てたわけではないようですが、解決できたようで良かったです。複数のソースに当たることで、「これで出来るはずなんだ」と言う自信を持ってチェックするとスペルミスのような単純ミスが早く見つかると言うことはあるようです。かなりお節介気味ではありますが、ご参考までに。

Comment: App groupの設定は，送信側，受信側の2箇所必要で，Extensio側の設定ミスでした。

Comment: なるほど。そういった経験を共有してくださることは私自身を含め、多くの開発者に役立つだろうと思います。少しお時間をとって、回答の形で書き込んで(それを承認していただくと)いただければ、より多くの方が見つけやすくなるかと思いますので、できるだけお願いします。

Comment: コメントいただいたことがきっかけとなり、解決できました。後日、回答にまとめておきたいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。